# How to handle bytes in c++?

Tags: c++, hash, byte

I have a program in python that I want to convert to c++ but have no clue how. I am currently stuck at the first part which is handling bytes. I am thinking that I can convert the bytes into a hash, but I would rather do it the straight forward way my python program does it. Here is my python program as a reference:

```
def sortHandshakes(in_1, in_2):
    if len(in_1) != len(in_2):
        raise 'lengths do not match'
    in_1_byte_list = list(bytes(in_1))
    in_2_byte_list = list(bytes(in_2))
    for i in range(0, len(in_1_byte_list)):
        if in_1_byte_list[i] < in_2_byte_list[i]:
            return (in_2, in_1)
        elif in_1_byte_list[i] > in_2_byte_list[i]:
            return (in_1, in_2)
    return (in_1, in_2)

def crackPassword(handshakeDict):
    ap_mac = handshakeDict['ap_mac']
    sta_mac = handshakeDict['sta_mac']
    sta_nonce = handshakeDict['sta_nonce']
    eapol_frame_zeroed_mic = handshakeDict['eapol_frame_zeroed_mic']
    ap_nonce = handshakeDict['ap_nonce']
    mic = handshakeDict['mic']
    SSID = handshakeDict['SSID']
    max_mac, min_mac = sortHandshakes(ap_mac, sta_mac)
    max_nonce, min_nonce = sortHandshakes(ap_nonce, sta_nonce)

    message = b''.join([
        b'Pairwise key expansion\x00',
        min_mac,
        max_mac,
        min_nonce,
        max_nonce,
        b'\x00'
    ])
    while True:
        password_guess = input('enter guess: ')
        password_guess = ''.join(password_guess).encode()
        
        pmk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', password_guess, SSID.encode(), 4096, 32)
        kck = hmac.new(pmk, message, hashlib.sha1).digest()[:16]
        calculated_mic = hmac.new(kck, eapol_frame_zeroed_mic, hashlib.sha1).digest()[:16]

        if calculated_mic == mic:
            print('correct, password is {}'.format(password_guess.decode('ASCII')))
            break
```

here is an example of an ap_mac: `\xac;w\xe6\x9d\xc8`. However if I try to set a `char *`
variable equal to it, I get an error.
`char * ap_mac = "\xac;w\xe6\x9d\xc8";` Which results in the error `ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]`. Are there any good libraries in c++ for doing specifically what I want to do?

Comment: Just to address your initial issue, the `char *` should be constant, e.g. `char const *` or `char const * const` (depending on whether you want the pointer itself to be modifiable).

Comment: Use **const** char * for the string literal

Comment: Sorry, library recommendations are off-topic here. Additionally, using a literal character string here is only going to end in tears, as soon as one of those bytes is a 0x00 byte. Literal character strings is not the right approach.

Comment: You can't simply do line-by-line translations from Python (or any other language) to C++.  It requires you to know both source and destination languages, and know what the program is supposed to do.  Once you know that information, then you need to rewrite, not just "translate" to C++.  That rewrite can be anything and everything, with the final C++ program not looking anything like Python.

Comment: I have two constructive criticisms/points of feedback for you. The first is this sentence: `Are there any good libraries in c++ for doing specifically what I want to do?` That is specifically off-topic for SO. We don't do library recommendations here because that usually attracts spam answers which both do't help you or the site.

Comment: The second is that I think your question is good (other than the off-topic part), but a little broad. Could you focus your question a bit and focus on a specific problem you're having? It'd be really nice if you could focus on the specific python part you're having trouble with, and the C++ code you tried to replicate it, as well as the C++ error you're getting. That will help you get a better answer.

Comment: I do not know what kind of type you can input to your function as `handShakeDict` but for c++ you should use std::string with the hexadecimal representation (only the characters, not the \x or 0x) or std::vector<uint8_t>. If you take the string option, then use stringstream and std::hex to get your bytes.

Comment: Search [softwarerecs.se] for appropriate libraries.

Comment: When referring to *bytes*, use the `uint8_t` data type.  A `char` can be signed, unsigned or `char`; it's up to the compiler or the platform.  Also, a `char` is defined by range, at least 256 values, could be more.  The `uint8_t` is defined as **unsigned 8 bits**.